# Knowledge-base of typical/notable values of attribute

Tags: nlp, english

For processing English language, we use semantic networks, such as [ConceptNet](http://conceptnet.io), to check various relations (e.g., **part-of**, **used-for**, etc.) between objects (typically nouns).

We are curious about knowledge-base concerning **typical** or **notable values** of an **attribute**. We attach some examples.

- typical values of a traffic light: *red*, *orange*, *green*
- typical values of an operating system: *Windows*, *Linux*, *Mac*, *Android*, etc.
- notable values of age: *18*/*21* (age restriction), *50*/*60*/*70* (celebration)

Comment: Are you asking more for a database or a tool?

Comment: A database, please.